# Is it possible to set preloadedState dynamically with RTK configureStore?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a unique situation in which my `<Provider>` component (and entire Redux Store) is exported from a middleware application to multiple front end React apps. The middleware has its own set of reducers but the client apps can inject their own reducers into the store when they call the provider.

It is now being asked that I accept an initial state (preloadedState) object when the Provider is called so that the initial state of the app can be loaded with dynamic initial state. This object will be an arbitrary set of state data (with corresponding reducers) so I'll have the data structures correctly with the shape in the reducers, but I won't know what values they're sending.

Here's the basic ReduxStore set up, changed here for simplicity:

ReduxStore.ts

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ExampleReducer } from './slices/ExampleSlice';

export const reducer = {
  example: ExampleReducer
};

const ReduxStore = configureStore({
    middleware: ...,
    reducer,
});

export default ReduxStore;
```

CoreProvider.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers, ReducersMapObject, AnyAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import ReduxStore, { reducer } from './ReduxStore';

export type ConfigProps = {
    newReducers?: ReducersMapObject<unknown, AnyAction>;
    preloadedState: Object;
};

const CoreProvider: React.FC<ConfigProps> = ({
    children,
    newReducers,
}) => {
    const newReducer = combineReducers({ ...newReducers, ...reducer });
    ReduxStore.replaceReducer(newReducer);

    return <Provider store={ReduxStore}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default CoreProvider;
```

index.jsx

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <CoreProvider newReducers={{ arbitrary: arbitraryReducer }}>
            <App />
        </CoreProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Now, I'm aware of the reasons I should NOT do this, and I am aware that initial state comes from the reducers themselves, which is handled when the reducers are merged with the default reducers when the Provider is called.

I know that configureStore accepts a preloadedState option but where I'm stuck is how to dynamically pass a preloadedState coming in as a prop from the Provider component. I have tried wrapping the configureStore call inside a function that is called within the Provider component, which does indeed set the initial state, but my ReduxStore export within ReduxStore.ts is undefined due to the way the app loads and the configureStore is called.

Provider calling configureStore with preloadedState props:

```
import { initReduxStore, reducer } from './ReduxStore';

const CoreProvider: React.FC<ConfigProps> = ({
    children,
    newReducers,
    preloadedState
}) => {
    const newReducer = combineReducers({ ...newReducers, ...reducer });
    const ReduxStore = initReduxStore(preloadedState, newReducer);

    return <Provider store={ReduxStore}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default CoreProvider;
```

ReduxStore with exported configureStore function and undefined ReduxStore export:

```
export const reducer = {
  example: ExampleReducer
};

let ReduxStore;

export const initReduxStore = (incomingState, incomingReducer) => {
  if (ReduxStore) return ReduxStore;
  
  const store = configureStore({
      middleware: ...,
      preloadedState: incomingState,
      reducer: incomingReducer,
  });
  
  ReduxStore = store;
  return ReduxStore;
};

export default ReduxStore; // This becomes undefined because the file loads before the Provider component calls the initReduxStore function
```

The ReduxStore export is undefined because the file loads before the Provider component calls the initReduxStore function and ReduxStore is undefined at the time it's exported.

Is there a known way that I have overlooked to easily set the preloaded state object when the provider is called? Should I restructure how the ReduxStore is created?

In short terms, how do I get the preloadedState prop from my Provider to my configureStore, while still exporting the ReduxStore to the rest of the app?

```
export const ReduxStore = configureStore({
  preloadedState,
  reducer,
});

// HOW DO I CONNECT THESE

const CoreProvider: React.FC<ConfigProps> = ({
    children,
    newReducers,
    preloadedState
}) => {

    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default CoreProvider;
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't. The `preloadedState` option can only be passed in when you call `configureStore()`.  Once the store is created, the *only* way to update the store state is to dispatch an action.

On top of that, behavior such as replacing the reducer or dispatching actions would qualify as a side effect, and React components *must not* have side effects directly in the rendering logic.

The closest suggestion I have would be a `useLayoutEffect` hook in this component that watches for changes to the provided reducers or state, and does the `store.replaceReducer()` call.

Also, you could have a wrapping reducer that watches for some kind of a "merge in this additional state" action, and returns the updated state with the additional fields.

But overall, this is a very unusual use case, and not something Redux is really designed for.

Comment: That's what I kind of figured. Everything about this use case feels off and gross so it makes sense that there's no built in or straight forward approach to this. I'll take a look at your suggestions and see if there's a way to accomplish this with useLayoutEffect and replaceReducer, but I would agree that Redux isn't designed for this and probably the best way to handle is to dispatch actions to set the state. I'll update if I find a good work around. Thanks!